# Ошибка при запуска hadoop программмы: java.io.IOException

Tags: solaris, map-reduce, java, распараллеливание, c++

```
using namespace std;

#include "hadoop/Pipes.hh"
#include "hadoop/TemplateFactory.hh"
#include "hadoop/StringUtils.hh"
#include "libpq-fe.h"

extern "C" {
    #include "traverser.h"
}

class IndexMap:public HadoopPipes::Mapper {
  public:
    IndexMap(HadoopPipes::TaskContext & context) { }
    void map(HadoopPipes::MapContext & context) {
        std::vector<std::string> paths = HadoopUtils::splitString(context.getInputValue(), "rn");
        unsigned int k = 4;
        unsigned int l = 0;
        string concatpaths[k];
        if (paths.size() % k == 0) {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                concatpaths[i] = paths[l];
                l = l + paths.size() / k;
            }

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                for (unsigned int j = 1; j < paths.size() / k; ++j) {
                    concatpaths[i] = +" " + paths[i * paths.size() / k + j];
                }
            }
        } else {
            l = 0;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                concatpaths[i] = paths[l];
                l = l + paths.size() / (k - 1);
            }
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k - 1; ++i) {
                for (unsigned int j = 1; j < paths.size() / (k - 1); ++j) {
                    concatpaths[i] = +" " + paths[i * paths.size() / (k - 1) + j];
                }
            }
            for (unsigned int j = 1; j < paths.size() - paths.size() / (k - 1) * (k - 1); ++j) {
                concatpaths[k - 1] = +" " + paths[(k - 1) * paths.size() / (k - 1) + j];
            }
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                context.emit(concatpaths[i], "0");
            }
        }
    }
};

class IndexReduce:public HadoopPipes::Reducer {
  public:
    IndexReduce(HadoopPipes::TaskContext & context) { }
    void reduce(HadoopPipes::ReduceContext & context) {
        long int count = 0;
        long int result = 0;
        std::vector<std::string> processedpaths = HadoopUtils::splitString(context.getInputValue(), " ");
        result = Configure("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/c++/hadoopc++/src/nsindexer.conf");
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < processedpaths.size(); ++i) {
            count = Traverser(processedpaths[i].c_str());
        }
        context.emit(processedpaths[processedpaths.size() - 1], HadoopUtils::toString(count));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return HadoopPipes::runTask(HadoopPipes::TemplateFactory<IndexMap, IndexReduce> ());
}
```

Запустил ее с помощью команды

> `root@one: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin#. ./hadoop pipes -D hadoop.pipes.java.recordreader=true -D hadoop.pipes.java.recordwriter=true -input input/paths.txt -output outnewdir1 -program bin/parindex`

Выдало ошибку:

> `12/08/30 03:40:24 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
> 12/08/30 03:40:24 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
> 12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
> 12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating parindex in /tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/local/archive/-7785595679055918834_2050052313_1927350978/filebin-work--3826230438226227897 with rwxr-xr-x
> 12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Cached bin/parindex as /tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/local/archive/-7785595679055918834_2050052313_1927350978/filebin/parindex
> 12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Cached bin/parindex as /tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/local/archive/-7785595679055918834_2050052313_1927350978/filebin/parindex
> 12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
> 12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
> 12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
> 12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
> 12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
> 12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
> 12/08/30 03:40:25 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application.<init>(Application.java:103)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.PipesMapRunner.run(PipesMapRunner.java:68)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
> 12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
> 12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
> 12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
> 12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1265)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.runJob(Submitter.java:248)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.run(Submitter.java:479)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.main(Submitter.java:494)`

Comment: Не имею ни малейшего представления о том, что такое Hadoop, но судя по логам прога не смогла загрузить нативные библиотеки Hadoop для вашей платформы и начала грузить/искать его Java реализацию и накрылась на этом этапе медным тазиком. Возможно из-за того, что не смогла открыть/найти JAR с либой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@ivan31](/users/4705/ivan31)](/users/4705/ivan31), обратите внимание:

```
The native hadoop library is not built by default since not  everyone is interested in building them
```

видимо их (native hadoop librarys) надо собирать самому и куда-то прописывать (возможно в LD_LIBRARY_PATH или что там в солярисе?).

Я наткнулся на это [здесь](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.18.3/native_libraries.html#Building+Native+Hadoop+Libraries).

А Вы, вообще-то, всю информацию про этот HADOOP изучили? Судя по всему пакет большой и инфы много.

Судя по ответам на Ваши предыдущие вопросы здесь спецов по этому продукту еще нет.

Comment: @ivan31, я написал солярис, помятуя о Ваших вопросах по сборке программы с hadoop на С++ в солярисе (а я тогда ошибочно думал, что в линуксе), а теперь только заметил метку *linux* в этом вопросе.

Вы сейчас в какой системе делаете?